# How to POST selected form row(s) by Checkbox (PHP)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I checked many different questions but almost all of them was about to POST checkbox value.    What I'm trying to do is to POST only the rows where the checkboxes selected.

Form contents retrived from query of 3 joined tables with AJAX from another PHP file. This is to provide live update by dropdown selection to filter results for Customers.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM z_sales_consigne AS a LEFT JOIN z_sales_price AS b ON a.SKU = b.SKU LEFT JOIN z_sales_discount AS c ON c.CustomerID = a.CustomerID WHERE a.CustomerName = '".$_POST["CustomerName"]."'";
```

form.php

```
<form name="SalesAdd" action="sls-calc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="porequest"/>
<td width="30px" style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="text" name="item_price[]" id="item_price"  value="'.$row["price"]. '"/>
    <input type="text" name="item_rate[]" id="item_rate"  value="'.$row["rate"]. '"/>
    <input type="text" name="item_discount[]" id="item_discount"  value="'.$row["Discount"]. '"/>
    <input type="checkbox" id="addProduct" name="Product[]" value="'.$row["id"]. '">
</td>
<button type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info" >
</form>
```

Posted sls-calc.php

```
foreach($_POST['Product'] as $key=>$check) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td width='120px'>".$_POST["item_price"][$key]. "</td>";
                echo "<td width='400px'>".$_POST["item_rate"][$key]. "</td>";
                echo "<td width='90px'>".$_POST["item_discount"][$key]. "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";  
            }
```

Original form rows with selection:
[image]

When I submit; result start from the first row as much as selected checkbox amount.
[image]
But result should contain the data of selected checkboxes rows
[image]
What should I do to only get rows of selected checkboxes?

EDIT

```
array (size=6)
  'item_price' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '112,16' (length=6)
      1 => string '112,16' (length=6)
      2 => string '254,87' (length=6)
      3 => string '254,87' (length=6)
      4 => string '254,87' (length=6)
      5 => string '254,87' (length=6)
      6 => string '254,87' (length=6)
  'item_rate' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '8' (length=1)
      1 => string '8' (length=1)
      2 => string '8' (length=1)
      3 => string '8' (length=1)
      4 => string '8' (length=1)
      5 => string '8' (length=1)
      6 => string '8' (length=1)
  'item_discount' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '20' (length=2)
      1 => string '20' (length=2)
      2 => string '20' (length=2)
      3 => string '20' (length=2)
      4 => string '20' (length=2)
      5 => string '20' (length=2)
      6 => string '20' (length=2)
  'productChk' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'on' (length=2)
      1 => string 'on' (length=2)
  'productId' => 
    array (size=7)
      0 => string '46' (length=2)
      1 => string '46' (length=2)
      2 => string '46' (length=2)
      3 => string '46' (length=2)
      4 => string '46' (length=2)
      5 => string '46' (length=2)
      6 => string '46' (length=2)
  'save' => string '' (length=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is your looping through the indexes wrong.

Currently, you're looping through Product but the $key is the wrong variable to use

```
foreach($_POST['Product'] as $key=>$check) {

 'Product' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string '1' (length=1)
      1 => string '4' (length=1)
```

because of this, you have two items in the array with index 0 and 1, so your always going to be grabbing the first two rows like your example where you really want your $row["id"] value you set or the $check variable here.

Comment: Totally agree with you but I can't figure out how to keep in relation individual rows by checkbox selections

Comment: just want to confirm what that edit dump is, is that your post request? There is an easy way to do this, are you open to changing the structure of your HTML at all?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following.

```js
// Get the form
let form = document.querySelector('#porequest');

// Convert to a query string
let queryString = new URLSearchParams(new FormData(form)).toString()
console.log(decodeURI(queryString));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Assuming the following HTML Output -->
<form name="SalesAdd" action="sls-calc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="porequest" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td width="30px" style="text-align:center;">
      <input type="text" name="item_price[]" id="item_price" value="5" />
      <input type="text" name="item_rate[]" id="item_rate" value="8" />
      <input type="text" name="item_discount[]" id="item_discount" value="5" />
      <input type="checkbox" id="addProduct" name="Product[]" value="1" checked />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30px" style="text-align:center;">
      <input type="text" name="item_price[]" id="item_price" value="7" />
      <input type="text" name="item_rate[]" id="item_rate" value="9" />
      <input type="text" name="item_discount[]" id="item_discount" value="4" />
      <input type="checkbox" id="addProduct" name="Product[]" value="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30px" style="text-align:center;">
      <input type="text" name="item_price[]" id="item_price" value="3" />
      <input type="text" name="item_rate[]" id="item_rate" value="7" />
      <input type="text" name="item_discount[]" id="item_discount" value="3" />
      <input type="checkbox" id="addProduct" name="Product[]" value="3" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="30px" style="text-align:center;">
      <input type="text" name="item_price[]" id="item_price" value="2" />
      <input type="text" name="item_rate[]" id="item_rate" value="4" />
      <input type="text" name="item_discount[]" id="item_discount" value="2" />
      <input type="checkbox" id="addProduct" name="Product[]" value="4" checked />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button type="submit" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info">
</form>
```

The console shows what might be passed to PHP.

```
item_price[]=5&item_rate[]=8&item_discount[]=5&Product[]=1&item_price[]=7&item_rate[]=9&item_discount[]=4&item_price[]=3&item_rate[]=7&item_discount[]=3&item_price[]=2&item_rate[]=4&item_discount[]=2&Product[]=4
```

This will be in PHP like so:

```
var_export($_POST)( 
  'Product' => array ( 
    0 => '1', 
    1 => '4', 
  ),
  'item_price' => array ( 
    0 => '5', 
    1 => '7', 
    2 => '3', 
    3 => '2', 
  ),
  'item_rate' => array ( 
    0 => '8', 
    1 => '9', 
    2 => '7', 
    3 => '4',
  ), 
  'item_discount' => array (
    0 => '5', 
    1 => '4', 
    2 => '3', 
    3 => '2',
  ),
)
```

You can now see why if you use just the index of `$_POST['Product']`, you will get the same two elements from the other arrays.

You need to pass along  the ID in another field, such as a hidden field, and the look for the checked items.

```
<td width="30px" style="text-align:center;">
    <input type="text" name="item_price[]" id="item_price"  value="'.$row["price"]. '"/>
    <input type="text" name="item_rate[]" id="item_rate"  value="'.$row["rate"]. '"/>
    <input type="text" name="item_discount[]" id="item_discount"  value="'.$row["Discount"]. '"/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="productChk[]" />
    <input type="hidden" name="productId[]" value="'.$row["id"]. '" />
</td>
```

Now you have a flag to check in each row.

```
foreach($_POST['productId'] as $key=>$val) {
  if(isset($_POST["productChk"][$key])){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td width='120px'>".$_POST["item_price"][$key]. "</td>";
    echo "<td width='400px'>".$_POST["item_rate"][$key]. "</td>";
    echo "<td width='90px'>".$_POST["item_discount"][$key]. "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm now agree with you that checkbox point the right row to bring it up on POST but this piece also does the same thing that I already done. Just adds the ON value to POST for selected ones and list results starting from first line. so what is the difference now?

Comment: @no_leaf it will generate the correct results.

Comment: I understand what should be done from your suggestion but there is something that "I" can't understand. Please check the result on Edit. Result generated from the exact copy of your suggested Form and Foreach loop.

Comment: @no_leaf I am unable to properly test the solution. There is no way to test your site, with your PHP, and your Database. I am only able to speculate based on the details you have provided in your post. Base don my experience, this will give you the correct results, as you iterate each item and conditionally check for `on` to be set.

Answer (score 0):

It would benefit you to restructure your form data so that each input's name directly references the product to which it belongs.
Consider using the following scheme to build your form:

```
<input type="text" name="item_price_'.$row["id"].'" id="item_price_'.$row["id"].'"  value="'.$row["price"]. '"/>
<input type="text" name="item_rate_'.$row["id"].'" id="item_rate_'.$row["id"].'"  value="'.$row["rate"]. '"/>
<input type="text" name="item_discount_'.$row["id"].'" id="item_discount_'.$row["id"].'"  value="'.$row["Discount"]. '"/>
<input type="checkbox" id="addProduct_'.$row["id"].'" name="Product[]" value="'.$row["id"].'">
```

You see now every key will include the id of the product, so when handling the form you just get the selected id's from `$_POST['Product']` and pick out the fields you need like so:

```php
$products = [];
foreach($_POST['Product'] as $id){
    $product[] = [
        'id'       => $id, // warning: should be sanitized
        'price'    => $_POST["item_price_$id"], // warning: should be sanitized
        'rate'     => $_POST["item_rate_$id"], // warning: should be sanitized
        'Discount' => $_POST["item_discount_$id"], // warning: should be sanitized
    ];
}
var_dump($products);
die();
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but here is the main issue is $row["id"] is always constant depending on the dropdown selection. As seen on EDIT output, currently it seems 46, but with another dropdown selection for Customer, it iwll be changed for all. With the code you send my output is empty. Because Price Rate and Discount does not have referance to $row["id"] where it is 46 on this example. What do you suggest?